# Angularjs default action form submit

Tags: forms, angularjs, submit, action, default

My angular application needs to submit a form to a vendor. They then redirect the user to a page that I specified earlier in the process.

So I want standard, non-angular html form submit behaviour.

The documentation (details below) makes it sound like all I need to do is add an action attribute to my form element. I have tried this and it does not work.

Has anyone used this functionality in angular? Is there another step that I am missing?

---

The relevant section of the documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form is:

Submitting a form and preventing the default action
Since the role of forms in client-side Angular applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic should be triggered to handle the form submission in an application-specific way.

For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular does that. When you provide an `action` on the form, it should do exactly what you're trying to do (do a javascript thing, then submit the form).

[Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/WqclGZffErnW1HSHDfYm?p=preview)

In the plunk, you can see the `$scope.submitted` say 'submitted' just before the form submission kicks the page over to the submitted.html

Comment: i have a problem doing this whereby no values (parameters) are submitted. any ideas?

Comment: code? set up a fiddle or a plunk and I can will take a look.

Comment: thanks for reply, i found the answer. actually more fundamental.  on the `ng-submit` I set a `signingIn` property to `true` - this was bound to the `ng-disabled` state of the username and password.  Disabled fields are not submitted in a `post` and as the ng-submit occurs before the post the username and password values were always null.  I changed the behaviour so that the `ng-readonly` directive was used instead of `ng-disabled`. thanks anyway